# How to extract all the dependencies from a Maven project for standalone offline building?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I know that I am not the only person that might need to send a Maven project to someone that doesn't have access to my private remote repository and only needs to build the project in a stand alone fashion.

In my case I need to send my Mavenized project to a customer that doesn't have access to our internal Archiva instance where we host all of our dependencies.

**How can I create a stand alone Maven project with all the dependencies to build the project in a stand alone fashion?**

*NOTE:* I don't want to just export the dependencies, I need an automated way to add them to the stand alone local repository as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure settings to use

```
< localRepository >${some.location.in.your project}< /localRepository >
```

[This](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) describes how to configure settings. After that you run online build and package your project with repository. Unpack and you should be able to build in offline mode.

Comment: you don't need to set `<localRepository>` in the `settings.xml` file, you can just specify `-Dmaven.repo.local=` on the command line and accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

see dependency plugin.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html
This can help you to download all internet :-)
run this goal with -Dmaven.repo.local=path to where you want everything.